# Non Performant MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query that takes about 20 seconds to execute:

```
select *
from be.`jobs`
where `scheduled_at` <= '2021-08-30 02:17:13'
  and `assigned_worker_id` is null
  and `is_deleted` = false
order by `scheduled_at` asc
limit 10;
```

The Explain:

[image]

Relevant Table Definitions:

Jobs (10 millions records)

```
create table jobs
(
    id                 char(36)        not null
        primary key,
    customer_id        bigint unsigned not null,
    scheduled_at       datetime        not null,
    assigned_worker_id bigint          null,
    is_deleted         tinyint(1)      not null,
    description        text            not null
)
    collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

create index idx_queue
    on jobs (scheduled_at, assigned_worker_id, is_deleted);
```

Workers (50 Records)

```
create table workers
(
    id         bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    name       text      not null,
    email      text      not null,
    created_at timestamp null,
    updated_at timestamp null
)
    collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to improve the performance of this query (ideally under a second)?

Note: I have gotten the records in the desired time by creating a summary table and then querying that.

i.e)

```
insert into unassigned_jobs
select jobs.id, customer_id, scheduled_at, assigned_worker_id, is_deleted, description
from `jobs`
         left join `workers` on assigned_worker_id = workers.id
where workers.id is null
  and is_deleted = false;
```

```
select *
from be.`unassigned_jobs`
where `scheduled_at` <= '2021-08-26 02:17:13'
order by `scheduled_at` asc
limit 10;
```

Comment: Change the index to: (is_deleted, assigned_worker_id, scheduled_at).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
select j.*
from be.jobs j
where j.scheduled_at <= '2021-08-30 02:17:13' and
      j.assigned_worker_id is null and
      j.is_deleted = false
order by j.scheduled_at asc
limit 10;
```

You want an index on `(is_deleted, assigned_worked_id, scheduled_at)`.  The first two columns can be in either order,  `scheduled_at` should be the last column in the index.

This index will filter on the first two columns, because of the equality.  It can use the third column as well -- and if you are lucky, avoid the `order by`.  Based on your comment, the optimizer is eliminating the sort for the `order by` so you are "lucky".

Comment: Thank you. Applying your index reduces the query execution time to 7ms! Do you mind describing how you decided on that particular index? I see the examined rows is now 28,072 (previously 73,107), which I assume is the reason for the performance improvement. I was under the impression that the order of the predicates should dictate index order (hints the reason for having scheduled_at first).

Comment: 99.997% improvement.  That's pretty good.  I'll try to pat myself on the back ;)

Comment: @KennonYoung - Where are you getting "examined" rows?  `EXPLAIN` is an approximation, sometimes very far off.  The slowlog and changes to `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'Handler%';` are precise.

Comment: More on how to how to arrive at that optimal index:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql